# Help with simple vector/operator algebra derivation

Tags: linear-algebra

Given

$$
\hat{O}\vec{a} = \vec{b}
$$

Show that

$$
b_i = \sum\limits_j O_{ij}a_j
$$

---

Using that $\vec{b} = \sum\limits_i\vec{e}_ib_i$ and multiplying from the right with $b_j$ gives

$$
b_i = \vec{e}_j\vec{b}
$$

Plugging in for $\vec{b}$ (first equation) gives

$$
b_i = \vec{e}_j \hat{O}\vec{a}
$$

Now using that $\vec{a} = \sum\limits_k\vec{e}_k a_k$ gives

$$
b_i = \vec{e}_j \hat{O} \sum\limits_k\vec{e}_k a_k
$$

Now using that $\hat{O}\vec{e}_k = \sum\limits_k O_{kl}\vec{e}_l$ results in

$$
b_i = \sum\limits_k \sum\limits_l \vec{e}_k \vec{e}_l O_{kl}a_k
$$

The sum over $l$ only survives for $k=l$ and so we get

$$
b_i = \sum\limits_k O_{kl}a_k
$$

which kind of looks like the correct answer. My indeces are all over the place, though! I don't know how to properly introduce new indeces. Any guidance is appreciated!

Comment: I disagree with the third line '$b_i = \vec{e}_j\vec{b}$'. You shouldn't end up with different free indexes on either side of the equation. In addition, those are two vectors which are 'multiplied' together on the RHS which is impossible. Could you specify what you mean by 'multiplying from the right'?

Comment: I think you might need to specify what $\hat{O}$ is. As far as I can see, what you're showing is simply true by how matrix multiplication works.

Comment: $\hat{O}$ is supposed to be a linear operator.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be a little more careful with your use of vectors and multiplication in your notation. Specifically, your first equation $b_i=\vec{e}_j\vec{b}$ doesn't make sense since an $n\times 1$ vector can't be multiplied by another $n\times 1$ vector. I would suggest $$b_i=\vec{e}^T_i \vec{b}=\vec{e}_i\cdot \vec{b}$$ with either the transpose or dot notation indicating the dot product between the vectors.

As for your problem, start with $\vec{a} = \sum\limits_k\vec{e}_k a_k$ substituted into $\hat{O}\vec{a}=\vec{b}$: $$\hat{O}\sum_k \vec{e}_k a_k = \vec{b}$$ At this point, move the summation to the front and use $$\hat{O}\vec{e}_k = \sum\limits_i O_{ik}\vec{e}_i$$ **This is different than your equation, you have the indices reverse on O**. Substituting in the above equation, we get:
$$\sum_k\sum_i O_{ik}\vec{e}_i a_k=\vec{b}$$
Notice the $O_{ki}$ and $a_k$ are scalars and commute with vectors, so we premultiply by $\vec{e}_j^T$ to get $$ \sum_k \sum_i \vec{e}_j^T\vec{e_i}O_{ik}a_k=\vec{e}_j^T \vec{b}$$
Since $\vec{e}_i^T\vec{e}_j\neq 0$ only if $i=j$, in the summation above only when the index $i$ is equal to $j$ do we get a nonzero quantity (note $j$ is a constant subscript, not changing with the summations). Thus only the $i=j$ term survives, giving $$\sum_k O_{jk}a_k=b_j$$
using my first equation on the RHS.

Comment: I'm slightly confused about the indeces used. In line 4, are the $i$ indeces in any way related to the $i$ indeces in line 1? I understand that indeces are arbitrary, but when I see the same indeces I instinctively look for connections.

Comment: And also changing the index of $O_{ik}$ to $O_{jk}$ in the last line.

Comment: The $i$ indices are only related in that they both happen to be subscripts of standard basis vectors. In general, indices in different equations aren't necessarily related; it is good practice for them to be, but not necessary. As for the changing of the index in the last line, I will add a little more explanation there.